# What happen to Centos version

Tags: centos, yum

I have a Centos server.

result

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release    
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

and

```
$ yum list installed
zip.x86_64                  3.0-1.el6_7-1                 @anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9
zlip.x86_64                 1.2.3-29.el6                  @anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9
...........                 ............                  ........................................
zlip-devel.x86_64           1.2.3-29.el6                  @anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9
```

All are packages of el6. My server is offline server and i install packages from private registry.
Now i can install packages for el6 but not for el7.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the EPEL RPM and the other packages on another machine:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm -P ~/Downloads
wget https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/zip-3.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm -P ~/Downloads
wget https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/zlib-1.2.7-19.el7_9.x86_64.rpm -P ~/Downloads
wget https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/zlib-devel-1.2.7-19.el7_9.x86_64.rpm -P ~/Downloads
```

...and then "sneakernet" them to your server (I would verify the hashes (https://getfedora.org/security/)). You also need to make sure that `/usr/sbin/ldconfig`, `/lib64/libc.so.6`, and `rtld` (from `glibc-2.17`) are on your system.

Once the RPM is verified, you can install them:

```
sudo yum install ~/Downloads/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install ~/Downloads/zip-3.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install ~/Downloads/zlib-1.2.7-19.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install ~/Downloads/zlib-devel-1.2.7-19.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
```